# Slicing a multidimensional array without a for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D array `r (1000 x 10 x 2000)` constructed as follows:

```py
q = np.random.normal(size=(10,2000))
r = np.random.normal(loc=q, size=(1000,10,2000))
```

This array, `r`, can be viewed as a `1000 x 10` matrix repeated 2000 times.

I would like to reduce this array according to the following rule:

- from each matrix select only the column which has the max value in the first row

The columns to be selected ca be obtained via: `np.argmax(r[0], axis=0)`.

The result should be a `1000 x 2000` matrix.

I wonder if it is possible to get something like that without using a `for` loop or list comprehensions.

---

Here is a `for` loop which achieves the above task:

```py
x = []
for i, idx in enumerate(np.argmax(r[0], axis=0)):
    x.append(r[:,idx,i])
x = np.array(x).T
```

Comment: FYI `r[0]` isn't the first row, but the first 2D slice along the first axis. Could you add a working loop-based solution?

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I never claimed that `r[0]` is a row.

Comment: You could use `np.take_along_axis(r,idx[None,None,:],axis=1)[:,0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I figured looks like this:

```py
r[:, np.argmax(r[0],axis=0), np.arange(2000)]
```

More elegant solutions are, of course, welcome.

Comment: I consider this to be a pythonic solution.

Comment: Having to add `np.arange(2000)` to the third dimension is not that intuitive though.

Comment: Your code might not be correct.

If your stack of matrices is `r = np.random.normal(loc=q, size=(1000,10,2000))` then `np.argmax(r[0], axis=0)` 
will only use the first one (`r[0]`) of these 1000 matrices.

Give it a try. Usually it is best not to start with shape `(1000,10,2000)` but with something like `(5,3,4)` and manually check if the results are correct.

Comment: There are **2000** matrices. My code uses the first **row** of each of these matrices to find the column indices of interest.

Comment: That looks fine.  The way I reason it is: `r` is (1000,10,2000); `r[0]` is (10,2000)`; `argmax` on axis 0 produces a (2000,).  That pairs with like sized `arange(2000)`, to produce a (1000,2000) selection.